# MongoDB Aggregation Error Returning wrong result

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I have my json object like this

```
{
    "_id": "5c2e811154855c0012308f00",
    "__pclass": "QXRzXFByb2plY3RcTW9kZWxcUHJvamVjdA==",
    "id": 44328,
    "name": "Test project via postman2//2",
    "address": "some random address",
    "area": null,
    "bidDate": null,
    "building": {
        "name": "Health Care Facilities",
        "type": "Dental Clinic"
    },
    "collaborators": [],
    "createdBy": {
        "user": {
            "id": 7662036,
            "name": "Someone Here"
        },
        "firm": {
            "id": 2520967,
            "type": "ATS"
        }
    },
    "createdDate": "2019-01-03T21:39:29Z",
    "customers": [],
    "doneBy": null,
    "file": null,
    "firm": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "MyFirm"
    },
    "leadSource": {
        "name": "dontknow",
        "number": "93794497"
    },
    "location": {
        "id": null,
        "city": {
            "id": 567,
            "name": "Bahamas"
        },
        "country": {
            "id": 38,
            "name": "Canada"
        },
        "province": {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "British Columbia"
        }
    },
    "modifiedBy": null,
    "modifiedDate": null,
    "projectPhase": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "pre-design"
    },
    "quotes": [{
        "id": 19,
        "opportunityValues": {
            "Key1": 100,
            "Key2 Key2": 100,
            "Key3 Key3 Key3": 200,
    }
    }],
    "specForecast": [],
    "specIds": [],
    "tags": [],
    "valuation": "something"
}
```

I am trying to aggregate using this query in MongoDB. My aggregation key is 4 level deep and also contains spaces. On all online examples shows me the aggregation at the first level. Looking to the online codes, I tried to re-iterate the same with my 4th level deep key.

```
db.mydata.aggregate([
  {$match: {"id": 44328 } } ,
  {$group: { _id: "$quotes.id",
    totalKey2:{ $sum: "$quotes.opportunityValues.Key2 Key2"},
    totalKey3:{ $sum: "$quotes.opportunityValues.Key3 Key3 Key3"}
  }
  }
]);
```

This should return

```
_id    totalKey2   totalKey3
 0 19    100         300
```

But it is returning

```
_id    totalKey2   totalKey3
 0 19      0         0
```

What am I doing Wrong?

Comment: Note that totalKey3 will return 200 as per the json data, not 300.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's not recommended to use space in field names in Mongo, it works as expected.

The problem with your query is that "quotes" is an array and you should first unwind it before grouping it.

This works as expected:

```
db.mydata.aggregate([
  { $match: { "id": 44328 } } ,
  { $unwind: "$quotes" },
  { $group: { _id: "$quotes.id",
    totalKey2:{ $sum: "$quotes.opportunityValues.Key2 Key2" },
    totalKey3:{ $sum: "$quotes.opportunityValues.Key3 Key3 Key3" } }
  }
]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Paulo. Worked as expected.